# Palindrome loop is always printing True

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm new here and new to Java.
I got a task to write a loop to check a palindrome with a given structure.
I'm only allowed to use a for loop and an if statement.
Here is my code. The result always prints as true.

```java
package palindrom;

/**
*
* @author Edwin
*/
public class Palindromcheck {
    static boolean is_palindrom(String str) {

         int n = str.length();
         for (int i = 0; i <= (n / 2) + 1; ++i) {
             if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
     }

     public static void main (String [] args){
         assert(is_palindrom(""));
         assert(is_palindrom("a"));
         assert(is_palindrom("aa"));
         assert(is_palindrom("aba"));
         assert(!is_palindrom("abab"));
         assert(!is_palindrom("abb"));

         if (true)
             System.out.println("Everything good!");
     }
}
```

Comment: When you say "is always giving out true" do you mean it always prints "everything good!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code works perfectly. None of the asserts should fire because you put a not `!` before all the strings that aren't palindromes.

The "if (true)" bit around the last println is a little odd. It doesn't do anything because true is always true.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the point about assertions, the line

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (n / 2) + 1; ++i)
```

is not quite right. If `n` is `0` or `1`, `(n / 2) + 1` is `1` so both cases result in a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The correct condition is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (n + 1) / 2; ++i)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that the `assert` statements that you provide in your code will probably not do what you expect them to with your current JVM settings, even if you remove the `!`s as suggested by Daniel T (you really should remove them though).

For example, if you compile and execute the following using standard JVM settings:

```
class Example {
    public static boolean yieldFalse() {
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert(yieldFalse());
        System.out.println("No error!");
    }
}
```

You will find that "No error!" prints to standard output every time. This is because assertions are not enabled by the JVM by default.

If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7865255/996249), you'll find how to enable them. However, it might be more convenient for you to instead write the following so that anyone running your code will get the output that you intend:

```
if (!is_palindrom("string")) {
    // throw an exception or print to the console
    // "string" is not a palindrome
}
```

Comment: Or, for less repetition, add a helper method: `static void test_palindrom(boolean expected, String str) { if (expected != is_palindrom(str)) System.out.println("Test failed:" + str); }`