# Why is assert passing all test cases when it shouldn't

Tags: java, testing, assert

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sumArray(8);
    }

    public static int sumArray(int nums){
       assert nums == 5;
       return nums;
    }
}
```

I was just wondering, when I pass a number that is not equal to 5, why doesn't the compiler throw any errors, since I am asserting that `nums` is equal to 5?

Comment: Why you expect from compiler to throw the error? Assertions are done runtime.

Comment: How would I get the compiler to show an error.

Comment: It won't, compiler is meant to check the syntax of your code not the execution. As far as your code syntax is correct you won't get any error.

Comment: But assert statement is not true, is there any way to show an error. Like this over here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865241/assertion-not-working  How can i do this on the command line or VSCode

Comment: *Run* your code and see what happens.

Comment: Can't you configure JVM arguments in VSC? Anyways, you can run it using `java -ea Main.java`

Comment: But assert statement is not true, is there any way to show an error. Answer is Yes. You need to understand difference between Compiler and JRE(Java Runtime Environment). So as syntax is correct now you need to run your program in order to find the result of assertions.

Comment: If I run the program, it doesnt print or throw any error.

Comment: You would need to enable the assertions as mentioned by @dan1st

Comment: How do I this in VSCode

Comment: (by passing `-ea` as JVM argument)

Answer (score 1):

If the program is running with assertions enabled, then the condition is checked at **runtime**. If the condition is false, the Java runtime system throws an `AssertionError`.

For backward compatibility, the JVM disables assertion validation by default. They must be explicitly enabled using either the `-enableassertions` command line argument, or its shorthand `-ea`

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-assert